# Content Provider not working on Nexus family devices

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, google-nexus

I'm developing an app with a ContentProvider to offer some inner files (binary files). When I deploy it on a Samsung Galaxy S, SII, or any other, it works perfectly, buy when I try it on a Galaxy Nexus or Nexus S, it doesn't work!

Scenario:

My ContentProvider can be accessed with two URIs. Depending on this URI, the provider creates a DataCursor (extending CrossProcessCursor) or ModelCursor (extending CrossProcessCursos also). The fact is that, in Nexus family, I access the first cursor (DataCursor) to retrieve an identifier, and it works perfectly, but when accessing the second one, it always throws "OutOfBoundsException" when trying

> getBlob()

method.

**Provider**

```
@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        // If the third app requieres DATA (phrase id, phrase string and phrase name)
        if(uri.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ProviderConstants.DATA_URI.toString())) {
            // Build the DataHelper and the customized cursor
            DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper(getContext());
            cursor = new DataCursor(dataHelper);
        } else if(uri.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(ProviderConstants.MODEL_URI.toString())) {            
            // Let's take the model id from the selectionArgs...
            if (selectionArgs != null && selectionArgs.length > 0) {
                String modelId = selectionArgs[0];

                // Get an instance to the persistent storage service...
                File file = FileManager.getDirectory(getContext(), modelId);
                FileSystemPersistentStorageService clientPersistentStorageService = new FileSystemPersistentStorageService(file);

                cursor = new ModelCursor(clientPersistentStorageService);
            } else {
                Log.e("ContentProvider", "Query without model id on selectionArgs");
            }
        }

        return cursor;
    }
```

If you need some code or anything, just ask for it please!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For starters: **1.** What are exact SDK versions present on your Android devices? **2.** What are the exact *SQLite* versions on each device (`adb shell sqlite3 --version`) **3.** Does the code work correctly in emulator? **4.** What is the full call stack, when you get *OutOfBoundsException*? **5.** How is *ModelCursor* implemented? **6.** What is you database model? **7.** How do you use your content provider (code)?

Comment: 1. From 2.3.3 to 4.0 (wide range of devices) 2. Does it matter? I can check them, but ModelCursor does not get data from SQLite, just from internal file storage.3. [To be tested, thanks]. 4. [link](http://pastebin.com/NS7zBSGx). 5. Just mehotd `getBlob` and the other ones required [link](http://pastebin.com/q4kMAEw3). 6. No database needed. 7. `Cursor modelCursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/model"), null, null, new String[] {modelId}, null);` - `modelCursor.getBlob(0);`

Comment: Have you tried to move the cursor to the first entry ? (`modelCursor.moveToFirst()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. It wasn't due to devices, but it was due to Android OS version.

Earlier versions from 4.0.3 had the method [fillWindow()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.6_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.fillWindow%28int,android.database.CursorWindow%29) of AbstarctCursor implemented one way, being not mandatory to set the cursor position to 0 for first item. After 4.0.3 ([as seen here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.fillWindow%28int,android.database.CursorWindow%29)), this method was modified, resulting on not setting the cursor position to 0.

The Exception thrown was:

```
07-31 11:35:09.938: W/System.err(2760): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
07-31 11:35:09.985: W/System.err(2760):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
07-31 11:35:09.989: W/System.err(2760):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-31 11:35:09.989: W/System.err(2760):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:44)
07-31 11:35:09.993: W/System.err(2760):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getBlob(CursorWrapper.java:122)
07-31 11:35:09.993: W/System.err(2760):     at es.agnitio.kivox.mobile.internal.ModelImporterAndroidImpl.importModelPackage(ModelImporterAndroidImpl.java:44)
07-31 11:35:09.993: W/System.err(2760):     at es.agnitio.kivox.mobile.internal.KivoxMobileBasicCode.importModel(KivoxMobileBasicCode.java:159)
07-31 11:35:09.997: W/System.err(2760):     at es.agnitio.kivox.mobile.internal.KivoxMobileBasicImpl.importModel(KivoxMobileBasicImpl.java:47)
07-31 11:35:09.997: W/System.err(2760):     at es.agnitio.kivoxmobile.testing.KivoxMobileBasicTrial.onCreate(KivoxMobileBasicTrial.java:63)
07-31 11:35:09.997: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-31 11:35:10.001: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-31 11:35:10.001: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-31 11:35:10.001: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-31 11:35:10.004: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-31 11:35:10.004: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-31 11:35:10.004: W/System.err(2760):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 11:35:10.008: W/System.err(2760):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 11:35:10.008: W/System.err(2760):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-31 11:35:10.008: W/System.err(2760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 11:35:10.012: W/System.err(2760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 11:35:10.012: W/System.err(2760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-31 11:35:10.012: W/System.err(2760):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-31 11:35:10.016: W/System.err(2760):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Which shows (after deep research), that the cursor index is not being setted on `fillWindow()`.

**SOLUTION**

To solve this "fragmentation" issue, just add [moveToPosition(0)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.6_r1/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#AbstractCursor.moveToPosition%28int%29) in methods like `moveToFirst()` or `move()` (with some app logic) of your custom cursor. This will make the cursor index to be setted to 0, avoiding the "-1" index request Exception.

Hope it helps anybody =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit in need of a crystal ball for this one, but...you could try two things:

- Move the cursor to the first entry, as [SteveR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291368/stever) suggested.
- Secondly, I encountered a similar problem while working on a Dell Streak 7" tablet. It was supposedly part of a list of devices with a particular exception in regard to accessing its internal storage. It was tricky to find, but was sorted with an if statement. It could be something similar, though I doubt it, especially since the Nexus is supposed to be the developer's device.

Maybe you should try to run the simplest possible ContentProvider test-app and see how it behaves on those devices.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I've already tested all of that. The point is that `moveToFirst()` returns `false`. It's like the system is not able to find the provider, weird, because in other devices it finds it.